# React Hooks - useMutation being called 50+ times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Basically I have this component that has 3 nested Query components and I want to call one of my mutations depending on whether one of these queries brought back data.

I want to call a mutation within a Query component, however I'm finding that my mutation is constantly updating the state which is causing the component to render over and over again multiple times. Essentially, it's executing my mutation 50+ times. I'm think i'm misunderstanding react hooks and how they work.

Example code:

```
import MyMutation from 'mutations/MyMutation.graphql'

const myComponent = ( {props} ) => {
  const [myMutation] = useMutation(MyMutation);

  return (
    <Query query ={GetUserData} variables={{ input: { id }}}>
      {({ data: userData, loading: dataLoading }) => (
        <Query query ={GetOtherData} variables={{ input: { id }}}>
          {({ data: otherUserData, loading: otherUserDataLoading}) => (
            <Query query ={GetOtherOtherData} variables={{ input: { id }}}>
              {({ data: otherOtheruserData, loading: otherOtheruserDataLoading }) => {

                if (dataLoading || otherUserDataLoading|| otherOtheruserDataLoading ) {
                  return null;
                }
                if (userData) {
                  myMutation({ variables: { input: { id, userData.updatedValue } } }).catch(() => {});
                }
```

Comment: Maybe you should change your func to an async/await function

Comment: Make sure you only render the state after it is done. My guess is you are setStating while the data is loading which makes the query run again with no stopping condition.

Comment: You didn't post `<Query>` component, didn't post `GetUserData` nor `useMutation`.. It's a bit difficult to help if we don't have all the pieces